# Removing file extensions batch or c#

Tags: c#, batch-file

Is there a way to mass remove file extensions in batch or c#

I have found ren *.loaded *.torrent very handy but with the files I work with the .loaded come after an .torrent extension, using the ren trick it becomes *.torrent.torrent :P (a bit OCD on file names).

So is there a way I can remove the file extension or would it be better to use another extension renaming solution?

Thanks in advance :)

(I thought c# as it might be great to let the user enter the extensions to change - though I could add this myself later, no idea how to start :P)

Comment: `ren *.torrent.loaded *.torrent`.

Comment: it skips the .torrent part and just moves on to the .loaded so it still becomes torrent.torrent (I think as its *.torrent the * includes the everything before the last period which would be why it skips any other extension present)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
rename *.* *.torrent
```

to remove extentions

```
rename *.* *.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.Net` you can do something like this:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\PathName");
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in dir.GetFiles("*.*"))
{
    File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, fileInfo.FullName.Replace(fileInfo.Extension, string.Empty));
}
```

You can replace `*.*` or `string.Empty` with other extensions.